# Finder Sync Extension won't run

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, module, findersync

I'm developing an app which includes a Finder Sync Extension, but now the extension won't run. For example, when I click "Customize Toolbar..." the toolbar button from my extension is not present. In system preferences the app extension is shown and I have checked the checkbox to enable it. I just tested a build from last week and it works fine, so I've broken something in the past week. Specifically it seems that when I broke up the code into modules (by adding new projects to the workspace and including them as embedded binaries) this problem began. The extension used to import a module, but in an effort to debug this I have now copied and pasted all shared code into the extension so that it doesn't depend on any other frameworks, but it still doesn't work. So the situation right now is that I have a Finder Sync Extension which has no dependencies on any other frameworks, and which won't run whether I run the app from a code-signed build or whether I run it directly from Xcode. Can anyone suggest what might be causing this? When I say that the extension won't run, I mean that when I run it from Xcode the console never logs anything, and when I run the app from a compiled build the Finder extension is not visible. I have tried deleting various folders from ~/Library/Containers but that did not help. As I said, a previous build currently works fine, so there is something that I did to the project's settings which is causing this. Thanks in advance.